# Can a module class method be called from a class nested in that module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

Is it possible to call a module's class method from a nested class method? For instance, if I had:

```
module A
  def self.foo
    'hello'
  end
end

module A
  class B
    def self.bar
      foo # Fails since A is not in B's ancestor chain
    end
  end
end
```

I know that I can call `foo` directly on `A` by using

```
def self.bar
  A.foo
end
```

But ideally I would like a way to have `A` be part of `B`'s ancestor chain if possible. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: There might not might a way around it, try using a class rather than a module.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a straightforward way to do exactly what you're asking. But you can move `A`'s self methods to instance methods in another module and have `B` extend that module:

```
module A
  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      'hello'
    end
  end
  extend ClassMethods
end

module A
  class B
    extend A::ClassMethods

    def self.bar
      foo
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ActiveSupport` (you already have it if you use Rails) you can do something like this:

```
def self.bar
  self.to_s.deconstantize.constantize.foo
end
```

More about inflectors:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html