# Organizing modules, services, and their shared methods in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to share a method between two ruby services, these services have a lot in common and they are inside the same module.

`TranslatorManager` is the module that onws the services: `CacheEraser` and `Translator`.

The shared method is `key_cache`, and I need to call it from `CacheEraser` and `Translator` services, just for them, it is only relationated to TranslatorManager, so I supose that this code must be in the module file `translator_anager.rb`

Each service has its file and all these files are in the the folder  `app/services/site/translator_manager/`

[image]

For me, this is the correct files organization, isn't it?

How can I call `key_cache` from `call` services method? this don't work

- I can't include Site::TranslatorManager from a nested class
- Need `key_cache` to be a class method? how can extend it **considering thar are distinct files**? I have try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845922/547341) and don't work.

**cache_eraser.rb**

```
module Site
  module TranslatorManager
    class CacheEraser < ApplicationService
      def initialize(company_id, text, head_locale, locale)
        @company_id, @text, @head_locale, @locale = company_id, text, head_locale, locale
      end

      def call
        #             ---> Don't work <----
        Rails.cache.delete key_cache(@company_id, @text, @head_locale, @locale)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**translator_manager.rb**

```
module Site
  module TranslatorManager
    def key_cache(company_id, text, head_locale, locale)
      # return a string
    end

    def translatable_key?(key)
      # return true or false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your `Site::TranslatorManager` module inside `CacheEraser` class:

```
module Site
  module TranslatorManager
    class CacheEraser < ApplicationService
      include Site::TranslatorManager # include module methods
      def initialize(company_id, text, head_locale, locale)
        @company_id, @text, @head_locale, @locale = company_id, text, head_locale, locale
      end

      def call
        #             ---> will work <----
        Rails.cache.delete key_cache(@company_id, @text, @head_locale, @locale)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this does not work: `NoMethodError: undefined method `key_cache' for #<Site::TranslatorManager::CacheEraser:0x0` `from app/services/site/translator_manager/cache_eraser.rb:11:in `call'`

Comment: all in the same folder, I'm going to add an image in the "question"

Comment: I've moved to previous folder and now your solution works

Comment: **I wonder if this is a sane solution**, .... is like including a module where you already are

Comment: @AlbertCatalà yes, you need store module inside app/services/site folder

Comment: Yes, I've seen and I've corrected, thank you. Even though it seems some weird this `include`, as I said before, is like including something that it is already included, isn't it?